# THREE.JS: Seeing geometry when inside mesh

Tags: 3d, geometry, three.js, textures

When entering the geometry, for example a sphere mesh, it acts as if the geometry doesn't exist. The color and texture are visible on the outside. But once I zoom into the mesh, the properties are gone.

How can I make the color and texture of a sphere mesh be visible inside the mesh?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

Or

```
mesh.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
```

three.js r.62

Comment: Thank you. Never knew about the option.